# Can't locate Switch.pm even when installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, perl

A colleage recently tried updating some code via conda and in the process broke our installation of bioperl.

When trying to run one of our normal inhouse scripts I now get the following error:

```
(base) ecoli@bact:~/Desktop/IMNGS_workflow$ perl ofline-analysis-Cornelia-Piggyy-Controls.pl 
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: /home/ecoli/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/ecoli/anaconda/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/ecoli/anaconda/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/ecoli/anaconda/lib/5.26.2 .) at ofline-analysis-Cornelia-Piggyy-Controls.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ofline-analysis-Cornelia-Piggyy-Controls.pl line 5.
```

Now the problem seems simple, Switch.pm needs to be installed. Well apparently it is according to `apt-get`;

```
(base) ecoli@bact:~/Desktop/IMNGS_workflow$ sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libswitch-perl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Even when using `cpan` I get the same status;

```
cpan[1]> install Switch
Reading '/home/ecoli/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 21 Jun 2019 00:41:02 GMT
Switch is up to date (2.17).
```

I assume the Switch.pm currently installed is somehow corrupted, is there a way to do a fresh install of Switch.pm?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` module is deprecated. See: [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html)

> Switch
>
> Switch is buggy and should be avoided. You may find Perl's new given/when feature a suitable replacement. See Switch statements in perlsyn for more information.

Use instead:

```
use feature qw(switch);

given($var){
  when(1) { print 'Number one'; }
  when(2) { print 'Number two'; }
  default { print 'Everything else' }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes some more sense. I have tried the code you suggested so the head of the script is ```#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Third-Party imports
use strict;
use warnings;
#use Switch;
use feature qw(switch);
use File::Path qw/make_path/;
use Bio::SeqIO;



given($var){
    when(1) { print 'Number one'; }
    when(2) { print 'Number two'; }
    default { print 'Everything else' }
}

``` But when I run it I get an error stating that ```give is experimental``` and that the code cannot be run due to too many erros

Answer (score 0):

Since you perl version seems old and you need Switch, you could force a reinstall with `cpan -f Switch`. But I think you have another problem, Switch.pm is not in your @INC. Lets say you found it with `locate -i switch.pm`, in dir `/home/libs`, add this line to the top of your script:

```
use lib '/home/libs';
```

Comment: `Switch` is deprecated and buggy, don't use it